# Android, Kotlin - @Nullable definition

Tags: android, dagger

I'm trying to learn Dagger. Most of tutorials are in Java and I have found strange issues. Here is AppModule class

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    companion object {

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideRequestOptions(): RequestOptions {
            return RequestOptions
                .placeholderOf(R.drawable.white_background)
                .error(R.drawable.white_background)
        }

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideGlideInstance(
            application: Application,
            requestOptions: RequestOptions
        ): RequestManager {
            return Glide.with(application)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
        }

        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        @Nullable
        fun provideAppDrawable(application: Application?): Drawable? {
            return ContextCompat.getDrawable(application!!, R.drawable.logo)
        }

    }

}
```

I'm trying to inject dependencies in activity :

```
class AuthActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {


    @Inject
    lateinit  var logo : Drawable
    @Inject
    lateinit var requestManager: RequestManager



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)
        setLogo()
    }

    private fun setLogo() {
        requestManager.
            load(logo).
                into(login_logo)
    }
}
```

However, Dagger throws an exception :

```
   app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/kotlintests/di/AppComponent.java:7: error: [Dagger/Nullable] android.app.Application is not nullable, but is being provided by @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable @BindsInstance com.example.kotlintests.di.AppComponent.Builder com.example.kotlintests.di.AppComponent.Builder.application(android.app.Application)
    public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<com.example.kotlintests.BaseApplication> {
                    ^
          android.app.Application is injected at
              com.example.kotlintests.di.AppModule.provideGlideInstance(application, …)
          com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager is injected at
              com.example.kotlintests.AuthActivity.requestManager
          com.example.kotlintests.AuthActivity is injected at
              dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [com.example.kotlintests.di.AppComponent → ActivityBuilderModules_ContributeAuthActivity.AuthActivitySubcomponent]
```

U understand what it means (I think so) but I tried to solve this issue in several ways and not succeeded. Any help, please ?

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly indicating that you forgot to call create instance of Application object inside your AppComponent.java class or may be it's there but not correctly initialised.

[Github Link for AppComponent class in Kotlin](https://github.com/yash786agg/Dagger2Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/app/di/component/AppComponent.kt)